# Many processes executed by one thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Is something like the following possible in C on Linux platform:
I have a thread say A reading system calls(intercepting system calls) made by application processes. For each process A creates a thread, which performs the required system call and then sleeps till A wakes it up with another system call which was made by its corresponding application process. When a process exits, it worker thread ceases to exist.

So its like a number of processes converzing on a thread which then fans out to many threads with one thread per process.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like a threadpool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for some kind of threadpool implementation and are not strictly limited to C I would recommend [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) (which is almost Boost). Its easy to use and quite lean. The only logic you now need is the catching of the system event and then spawn a new task thread that will execute the call. The threadpool will keep track of all created threads and assign work automatically to the threads.

**EDIT**

Since you are limited to C, try this [implementation](http://people.clarkson.edu/~jmatthew/cs644.archive/cs644.fa2001/proj/pthreadsPool/). It looks fairly complete and rather simple, but it will basically do the job.

Comment: I have the restriction of using C but what you describe is exatly what i want